# How to start a large number of quick jobs in Bash

Tags: bash, cygwin, task

I have 3000 very quick jobs to run that on average take 2/3 seconds.

The list of jobs is in a file, and I want to control how many I have open.

However, the process of starting a job in background (& line) seems to take some time itself, therefore, some jobs are already finishing before "INTOTAL" amount have got started...

Therefore, I am not using my 32 core efficiently.

Is the a better approach than the one below?

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x

INTOTAL=28


while true
do

    NUMRUNNING=`tasklist | egrep Prod.exe | wc -l`

    JOBS=`cat jobs.lst | wc -l`
    if [ $JOBS -gt 0 ]
    then

        MAXSTART=$(($INTOTAL-$NUMRUNNING))
        NUMTOSTART=$JOBS

        if [ $NUMTOSTART -gt $MAXSTART ]
        then
            NUMTOSTART=$MAXSTART
        fi
        echo 'Starting: '$NUMTOSTART 
        for ((i=1;i<=$NUMTOSTART;i++))
        do
            JOB=`head -n1 jobs.lst`
            sed -i 1d jobs.lst

            /Prod $JOB &

        done
        sleep 2
    fi


    sleep 3

done
```

Comment: @arco444 If I do that I get -bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: or search here for `[bash] xargs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at [`parallel`](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7581), which you should be able to install on Cygwin according to the release notes. Then running the tasks in parallel can be as easy as:

```
parallel /Prod {} < jobs.lst
```

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-cat-sh.-Resource-inexpensive-jobs-and-evaluation) for an example of this in its man page (and have a look through the plethora of examples for more about the many options it has).

To control how many jobs to run at a time use the `-j` flag. By default it will run 1 job per core at a time, so 32 for you. To limit to 16 for instance:

```
parallel -j 16 /Prod {} < jobs.lst
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am hoping to remain with my existing structure if possible as it works very well for larger jobs

Comment: `parallel` works very well for larger jobs too. And gives you a lot: output from the jobs as if they were run in serial with `-k`, showing progress bar with `--bar` option, resume from last unfinished job with `--joblog` and `--resume`...